# How to deserialize dynamic JSON fields with Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

How can I deserialize JSON a object with dynamic fields (like the one called stories in the code below) into an array of objects?

```
{
   stories: {
      -IhO1742Lki-Pit0snot: {
         sentences: {
            -IhO2fyAEn15XUge6HeY: {
               userName: "Giulia",
               text: "a dude created a new religion called PornDora"
            },
            -IhO2fyAEn15XUge6HeZ: {
               userName: "Will",
               text: "but it was kidnapped by a flying burrito copter"
            },
            -IhO2fyAEn15XUge6HeX: {
               userName: "Jasmine",
               text: "I went this morning at AngelHack hackaton"
            }
         }
      },
      -IhO-gNvUPHpB9fOn-Gm: {
         sentences: {
            -IhO0PBBnJavU2gfMcVO: {
               userName: "Giorgio",
               text: "I woke up alone in a dark alley and a yellow cat was starring at me"
            },
            -IhO11CWL9r6G4Pu8YXx: {
               userName: "Will",
               text: "the cat runned away when a blurred figure approached me and called my name"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

These below are the Java classes I'm using for deserialization:

```
public class Story {

    private String id;
    private List sentences;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public List getSentences() {
        return sentences;
    }
    public void setSentences(List sentences) {
        this.sentences = sentences;
    }

}
```

```
public class Sentence {

    private String id;
    private String text;
    private String userName;



    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you control the format of the JSON serialization? For example, could you adapt the following format instead:

```
{
    "stories": [
        {
            "id": "-IhO1742Lki-Pit0snot", 
            "sentences": [
                {
                    "id": "-IhO2fyAEn15XUge6HeY", 
                    "text": "a dude created a new religion called PornDora", 
                    "userName": "Giulia"
                }
            ]
        )
    ]
}
```

If you do control the serialization side, you could try using [Polymorphic Type Handling](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization) (PTH).

This will give Jackson enough type information to deserialize your objects.

Also see Tatu's [accompanying blog post](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2010/03/entry_372.html) for background info.

---

Here is a code snippet for PTH in Jackson 1.x. If you want to use Jackson 2.x, you'll leverage the [`com.fasterxml` packages](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) and need to change the code a little bit.

```
// import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
// import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonTypeInfo;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

public class MyObjectMapperProvider {
    final ObjectMapper defaultObjectMapper;

    public MyObjectMapperProvider() {
        System.out.println("MyObjectMapperProvider()");


        this.defaultObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        this.defaultObjectMapper.enableDefaultTyping(
            ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT
        );
        // .enableDefaultTyping();
        // .enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.OBJECT_AND_NON_CONCRETE);
        // .enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT); 
        // this.defaultObjectMapper.addMixInAnnotations(Bindable.class, MyObjectMapperProvider.MixIn.class);
        // this.defaultObjectMapper.addMixInAnnotations(DataModel.WriteOp.class, MyObjectMapperProvider.MixIn.class);
    }
}
```

---

By the way, the json you provided is not actually valid JSON. Try using

```
   {
        "stories": {
            "-IhO-gNvUPHpB9fOn-Gm": {
                "sentences": {
                    "-IhO0PBBnJavU2gfMcVO": {
                        "text": "I woke up alone in a dark alley and a yellow cat was starring at me", 
                        "userName": "Giorgio"
                    }, 
                    "-IhO11CWL9r6G4Pu8YXx": {
                        "text": "the cat runned away when a blurred figure approached me and called my name", 
                        "userName": "Will"
                    }
                }
            }, 
            "-IhO1742Lki-Pit0snot": {
                "sentences": {
                    "-IhO2fyAEn15XUge6HeX": {
                        "text": "I went this morning at AngelHack hackaton", 
                        "userName": "Jasmine"
                    }, 
                    "-IhO2fyAEn15XUge6HeY": {
                        "text": "a dude created a new religion called PornDora", 
                        "userName": "Giulia"
                    }, 
                    "-IhO2fyAEn15XUge6HeZ": {
                        "text": "but it was kidnapped by a flying burrito copter", 
                        "userName": "Will"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You can verify that your json is correct by passing it into `python -m json.tool`. On OS X, you can copy the json into your clipboard and pass it to `json.tool` as follows:

```
 > pbpaste | python -m json.tool
```

---

Here is a small example that leverages Jersey if you want to play around. Use `curl http://localhost:7654/sandbox/test` to exercise it:

MainClass.java

```
import java.net.URI;

import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer;
// import org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder;
import org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpServerFactory;
import org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class MainClass {
     private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainClass.class);
     public static final String PATH = "http://localhost:7654/sandbox/";
     public static void main(String[] args) {
          // create a resource config that scans for JAX-RS resources and providers
          // in com.mlbam.monitoring.lsg.data_aggregator package
          final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig()
                .packages("com.mlbam.internal")
                // .packages("com.mlbam.monitoring.collector.provis")
                .register(MyObjectMapperProvider.class)
                .register(JacksonFeature.class)
          ;

          // create and start a new instance of grizzly http server
          // exposing the Jersey application at BASE_URI
          final HttpServer grizzlyServerV1 = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(PATH), rc);
          LOG.info("Jersey app started with WADL available at {}application.wadl", PATH);
          try {
                Thread.sleep(10_000);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
          LOG.info("Stopping");
     }
}
```

MyObjectMapperProvider.java:

```
// import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
// import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonTypeInfo;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

import javax.ws.rs.ext.ContextResolver;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class MyObjectMapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {
    final ObjectMapper defaultObjectMapper;

    public MyObjectMapperProvider() {
         System.out.println("MyObjectMapperProvider()");

         this.defaultObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
         this.defaultObjectMapper.enableDefaultTyping(
               ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT
         );
         // .enableDefaultTyping();
         // .enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.OBJECT_AND_NON_CONCRETE);
         // .enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT); 
         // this.defaultObjectMapper.addMixInAnnotations(Bindable.class, MyObjectMapperProvider.MixIn.class);
         // this.defaultObjectMapper.addMixInAnnotations(DataModel.WriteOp.class, MyObjectMapperProvider.MixIn.class);
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
         System.out.println("MyObjectMapperProvider.getContext(" + type + ")");
         return this.defaultObjectMapper;
    }


    // @JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="@class")
    // public static class MixIn {
    // }
}
```

MyResource.java

```
import javax.inject.Singleton;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Singleton
@Path("test/")
public class MyResource {
    // public Thing[] state = {new Thing("asdf"), new Thing("foo"), new Thing("bar")};
    public String[] state = {"asdf", "foo", "bar"};

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response test() {
         return Response.ok(state).build();
    }
}
```

Dependencies (if using maven):

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Jersey Specific Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Actually, Jackson will convert a Map<String,Story> to something similar to the format you described